# How to resovle exeption HotChocolate.SchemaException: 'Unable to create instance of type ``.' GraphQl-Hotchocolate

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am new to Hotchocolate GraphQL framework and trying to create small solution just to see and understand how it works and what are the capabilities of the framework. I don't quite understand how to use this framework with EF core DbContext and how to register the dependencies in startup.cs class.

If anyone had the same problem or can explain how to do this in proper way, 
it will be great and thanks in advance.

[Check out the code](https://github.com/haris-begluk/Graphql-Hotchocolate-proj)

GRaphQL-Hotchocolate framework throwing an exeption when trying to create schema. [Exeption Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN0mj.jpg)

Comment: Code must be part of the question. Not in remote sources or images.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there were quite a few issues...

I have fixed them and the project runs now:
https://github.com/haris-begluk/Graphql-Hotchocolate-proj/pull/1

playground runs under http://localhost:[port]/graphql/playground.

Have fun with this.

Comment: Can you please share with us those issues? I have a similar error and cannot find the problem causing it.

Comment: I commend you for fixing OP's problem, but listing what had been done wrong and how you fixed them would have been of use to everyone facing the same problems.

Comment: Yeah I'd say I'm impressed but I can't tell what you did to fix it.